# Div's with absolute position aren't positioning equivalent

Tags: html, css

As you can see at the screenshot bellow, my vertical div's skill titles (coding,frameworks,methodologies) are not positioning equivalent.

Please tell me what's wrong, my CSS knowledge is a bit rusty now days. :)

```
.vc {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
}

.skill .title {
    left: -15px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: please send jsfiddle demo link

Comment: the whole problem with this design is : you rotate 3 different elements with varying width; you can add  container with  for div with class `.skill .title`. elements with same with width for all elements and then rotate the container

Comment: @SoheilGhahremani thanks mate, i did it this way with some more modifications. You can write this as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be happening because of the transform property on the title. By default, the transform-origin is the center of the box you're transforming. Since the text length,  and thus,  your box width varies between the titles, this results in different positioned rotation points relative to your main content.

You may want to try to move the transform origin to the 'center left'

Comment: Yes, it's because of the transform, if i set the origin to center left it positions at the right X axis. Although they are not centered in the Y axis correctly now. Look screenshot http://puu.sh/oZU7d/6589765b3b.png 
i've posted also jsfiddle link in comments above :) Thanks for your time

Comment: You can fix the vertical alignment  easily by wrapping each of your titles in another container,  and making sure that all of those containers have the same width. Next,  if you apply the transform on those,  instead of on the title elements themselves,  and center the text in the containers, you should be able to get the desired results.